# How to use only one Web.config for multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I work with a solution that have a lot of projects and I want to share only one `Web.config` for all the projects inside it because I have the configuration for my `Session State Server` set on it.

I searched a lot on the internet and I saw approaches like `configSource` and `Add As a Link`.

The `configSource` don't seems a good ideia because I'll need to create more than one file to configurate the State Server.

The `Add As a Link` I think it's better but when I try to run the project on Visual Studio 2015 I receive a pop up that follows:

[image: Debugging Not Enabled]

I don't know why I'm receiving this pop up because inside the `Web.config` already have the `debug="true"` and the file has the `Copy Always` option.

**EDIT 1:**

I tried to add a transform `Web.Debug.config`, but I continue receiving the same pop up.

[image]
[image]

Someone can help?

Comment: In most cases, unless the programmer went out of their way and changed it, regardless of how many config files you have, the only one which will be used is the one in the start-up application.

Comment: It is not possible to use the same config file for multiple web applications (if that is indeed what you are asking, which isn't very clear). The solution is to use a **single** application in most cases to avoid problems with sharing common items (files, sessions, logins, etc.) If these "extra" config files are for class libraries, you should reconsider that approach. Always pass configuration info into your class libraries from the consuming application so it has a chance to intervene if it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to add a debug transform for the web.config. Check out MSDN here: [Creating and Coding a Transform File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)

Basically you'll follow the instructions there to add a transform that looks like:

- Web.{build-profile-name}.config

So for example:

- Web.Debug.config

And in that you can enable your debugging so your original web.config can remain unchanged.

My disclaimer is that I'm not sure how it will work when the original web.config was added as a link. You could potentially add the transform as a sibling file in the original location, and also add it as a linked document.

Comment: I edited my question. Thank's for helping. Both "Add As a Link" or using the option "Add Config Transform" doesn't work.